# Programmatically Creating Attributes - Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am programmatically adding attributes to Prestashop 1.6 as follows:

```
$newGroup = new AttributeGroup();
$newGroup->name = $this->createMultiLangField('test');
$newGroup->public_name = $this->createMultiLangField('test');
$newGroup->group_type = 'select';
$newGroup->add();

$newAttribute = new Attribute();
$newAttribute->name = $this->createMultiLangField('test');
$newAttribute->id_attribute_group = $newGroup->id;
$newAttribute->add();
```

When I look in my catalog this attribute and its group are there and everything appears to be in order.  However, when I click combinations on any of my products after doing this, the ajax loader spins out indefinately (I can no longer create combinations on ANY of my products).  Has anybody experienced anything like this?

Comment: What does `Developper tools> Network` tells you about your ajax request/response?

Comment: The network window is showing status 200 OK, and nothing strange.  The javascript console is giving me "attrs is not defined"

Comment: can you provide us with your xml request for adding new attribute?

Answer (score 4):

The code should be:

```
$newGroup = new AttributeGroup();
$newGroup->name = $this->createMultiLangField('test');
$newGroup->public_name = $this->createMultiLangField('test');
$newGroup->group_type = 'select';
$newGroup->add();

$newAttribute = new Attribute();
$newAttribute->name = $this->createMultiLangField('test');
$newAttribute->id_attribute_group = $newGroup->id;
$newAttribute->add();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was careless and left the ->id off my original post.  It was in my code.

Comment: If you have solved the issue, I would be glad to know how for I'm stuck with the same problem.